# Connect to shared folder with username and password and copy files to that folder

Tags: cmd, deployment

I wanted to connect to a shared folder with user name and a password. After the connection is successful copy files to destination folder.

I know using "net use" command a shared folder can be mapped to a drive and after that I can use, I do not wanted to do that.

I am doing this to create a script to deployment a dotnet web application.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Note: powershell is not available in that server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `net use z: \\<network-location>\<some-share>\ password /USER:username` first and then `net /d z:` to clean up, if your primary concern is not to leave unnecessary shares. Unfortunately, you cannot include your credentials in any other standard CLI command.

Comment: A better way would be to give the deployment user (the user running the script) access to the deployment share (`\\<network-location>\<some-share>`). That way you won't have to store credentials in a script.